# Wicket - Progress/Multiple Label Updates

Tags: java, ajax, label, wicket, target

I'm not sure if this is even possible. It would seem like there would be a way to do this when you click a "submit" button.

```
private Button getButton(String id) 
{
    return new AjaxButton(id)
    {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
                setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) 
            {
                debug = "Beginning a process....";
                target.addComponent(debugLabel);

                //Perform the first process

                debug = "Beginning second process....";
                target.addComponent(debugLabel);

                //Perform the second process

                debug = "Finishing....";
                target.addComponent(debugLabel);

                //Perform the third process

                debug = "Done.";
                target.addComponent(debugLabel);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form)
            {
                //NO-OP
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If it's not possible is there an alternative to multiple real-time updates? I want it so there is a status label on the bottom updating and telling you how much progress is done in that one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use AjaxTimerBehavior, so that it updates your label every 1-2 seconds.

Code:

```
add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1))
        {
            @Override
            protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                target.add(label);
            }
        });
```

Obviously this solution uses dumb AJAX polling, so it is only advisable to use it on an intranet or other low traffic site.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to start the process that you want to have notifications about in another thread. Then you can update user session with information about the status which will be periodically checked by some ajax Behavior bound to label.

In wicket 6 you could also use `WebSocketBehavior`

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me. Could you provide a brief example in code?

Comment: I'll provide you with one when I'm home (in a few hours). Which wicket version do you use?

Comment: Not sure about that one. I reference a wicket-1.4.17.jar as one of my libraries in Eclipse.